# MySQL Query performance using latitude conversion

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I was trying to convert and format a latitude in degrees minutes to decimal degrees using MySQL Query which is taking around 0.4 seconds. 
Would like to know if I can reduce the number of functions in the below query to improve its performance further. Thank you.

```
SELECT  FORMAT( IF(LOCATE('.', -1.234) >0,
                        substr(-1.234*-1, 1,
                   LOCATE('.', -1.234*-1)-1),
                               -1.234*-1)+ (CAST(
   CONCAT( if ( LENGTH( substr(-1.234*-1,
                   LOCATE('.', -1.234*-1) + 1, 2) ) > 1,
                IF(LOCATE('.', -1.234)>0,
                        substr(-1.234*-1, LOCATE('.',
                               -1.234*-1) + 1, 2), '0'),
                 concat(substr(-1.234*-1,
                   LOCATE('.', -1.234*-1) + 1, 2), '0')), '.',
                        SUBSTR(-1.234*-1,
                   LOCATE('.', -1.234*-1)+3)) AS Decimal(10,3)
                )/60), 3
              ) *-1;
```

Comment: Additionally: if you store numeric values as varchars, you will have some troubles doing calculations with them, so the first thing to do would be to store them as/use a number (although you might already do that, since `1.234` is a number, while `'1.234'` would be a string; not sure if something got lost in your formatting though). A different formula will not change much about your execution speed: your query for one row should not take 0.4 seconds (unless running on hardware from 1965), so there might be some other problem with your system.

Comment: @Solarflare, The above solution worked for positive values like 1.234. But if it is a negative value like -1.234, Floor(-1.234) is converting the value to -2. Could you please suggest if there is any alternate for floor of negative value to not to round the number?

Comment: Same link, one answer below, stating the same thing, with a solution.

Comment: Huh?  `-1.234` does not look like "degrees minutes"

Comment: @RickJames, yeah.. I gave some example. The solution suggested in the other link by Solarflare is working but I dont see much different in the performance.

Comment: What is the answer supposed to be?